# MySQL Triggers - Error getting DDL for object

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I created two triggers and I am getting an error whenever I try to alter the 'Computers' table schema:

[image]

TRIGGER trgMarkUpd:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trgMarkUpd`
BEFORE UPDATE on Computers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    If old.OutofSync = 3 THEN
     SET new.OutofSync = 2;
     END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

TRIGGER trgMarkNew:

```
 DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER `trgMarkNew`
    BEFORE INSERT on Computers
    FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    SET new.OutofSync = 1 ;   
    END;
    DELIMITER ;
```

TRIGGER trgSoftwareLicenseDetails:

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER `trgSoftwareLicenseDetails`
    BEFORE UPDATE on SoftwareLicenseDetails
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    IF new.Flag = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO audithistory (audit_date, audit_field, audit_oldvalue, audit_changelog_fk, audit_newvalue, audit_assetid_fk) VALUES (Now(),''Software License Details'', (SELECT Title FROM SoftwareTypes WHERE ID = 
        (SELECT SoftwareNameFK FROM SoftwareLicenseDetails
        WHERE  ComputerFK=new.ComputerFK
        ORDER BY ID Desc
        LIMIT 1)), (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), ''License Added'',new.ComputerFK);

    ELSEIF new.Flag = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO audithistory (audit_date, audit_field, audit_oldvalue, audit_changelog_fk, audit_newvalue, audit_assetid_fk) VALUES (Now(),''Software License Details'', ''N/A'', (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), ''License Deleted'',old.ComputerFK);
    END IF;

END;
    DELIMITER ;
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the SQL??

Note that I did not get any error messages when creating the TRIGGERS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues with the syntax:

- End all triggers with `$$` (DELIMITER):

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trgMarkUpd` BEFORE UPDATE on Computers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   If old.OutofSync = 3 THEN
      SET new.OutofSync = 2;
   END IF;
-- END;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

- Use single quotes in strings:

```sql
...
-- LIMIT 1)), (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), ''License Added'',new.ComputerFK);
LIMIT 1)), (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Changelog as ChangelogID ), 'License Added',new.ComputerFK);
...
```